# DXF rending in QGIS independently of symboloys

Tags: qgis, color, rendering, autocad

I have imported a DXF file from AutoCAD into QGIS 3.20 and it has applied the rendering that it had in AutoCAD. I am trying to figure out how QGIS detects these settings so that when I run a process on the imported layer and get an output layer, I can make this new layer render with the same colours as the original did (and as it would in AutoCAD).

The colouring in the picture is the hatch colouring in AutoCAD, shows on a layer freshly imported into QGIS.

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: fyi has the changelog here (with gdal links) https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/209

Comment: While I think the context of Erik's answer is perhaps what you actually looking for, just use the styling of the original layer. If you are actually wanting to know exactly how QGIS/OGR finds those colours, it is in the DXF file and covered in the DXF specification.
https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colour of dxf-imports seems to be tied to the field "color" in the attribute table. You may use `data defined override` to set the colour of new layers to any value present in that field - but using this as default style would require all your new layers to have this field.

[image]